# parse date throws an error inside create job executed in cloud functions

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

i have a parse date in the sql statement in the order by clause for the bigquery createjob api getting executed by cloud functions and it throws an error.

The same sql statement executes without any issue in bigquery query editor console

```
sqlQuery="select * from <<datasetid>>.<<table_name>> where arrival_date not like '%Z%' order by parse_date('%d/%m/%Y',arrival_date)" ;
const options = {
        configuration: {
            query: {
                query: sqlQuery
            }
        }
   };
bigquery.createJob(options, function (err, job) {
        if (err) {

            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500);

        }
        job.getQueryResults(function (err, rows) {
            return res.status(200).send(rows);
        });
    });
```

Comment: i have a small correction in the code listed above.. there is a quote for the query string that is missing in the code above but in the cloud function i do have the quote..

Comment: i have copied the exact error message below : TypeError: stream.destroy is not a function at onResultSet (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/bigquery/node_modules/@google-cloud/paginator/build/src/index.js:242:24) at bigQuery.request (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/bigquery/build/src/job.js:385:17) at request_.then.err (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/bigquery/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/service.js:167:82) at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing this:

```
sqlQuery=select * from <<datasetid>>.<<table_name>> where arrival_date not like '%Z%' order by parse_date('%d/%m/%Y',arrival_date)
```

With this:

```
sqlQuery="select * from <<datasetid>>.<<table_name>> where arrival_date not like '%Z%' order by parse_date('%d/%m/%Y',arrival_date)"
```

Next time: Please, copy paste the exact error code you get.

Comment: i have a small correction in the code listed above.. there is a quote for the query string that is missing in the code above but in the cloud function i do have the quote.. i added the exact error in the comments above